# Table that contains many rows doesn't work

Tags: ajax, browser, vaadin, vaadin7

I've got a problem with Table in Vaadin.
I've created Table component with 4 columns that usually contains over 1000 rows. Each row consist of one custom_component (Two labels next to each other) and three raw text labels in other columns.

It works very well when I run Vaadin application on localhost and I access this app from localhost-computer. However if my colleague tries to access application from his computer over a real network, the UI got stuck after opening table or moving table scrollbar. By saying 'stuck' I mean it becomes unresponsive for 1 to 5 minutes and built-in Vaadin progress icon is still displayed (it should be closed).
A simple solution is to click refresh button in browser. After refresh UI is built from scratch and application works (at least until user enter table again or move scrollbar).

I've check Vaadin console and I noticed something strange behaviour. This is the log produced by accessing app and moving scrollbar in table from localhost computer:

```
"Tue Sep 02 12:13:09 GMT+200 2014 com.vaadin.client.VConsole"
INFO: Making UIDL Request with params:
"Tue Sep 02 12:13:09 GMT+200 2014 com.vaadin.client.VConsole" 
INFO: Sending push message: 
"Tue Sep 02 12:13:09 GMT+200 2014 com.vaadin.client.VConsole"
INFO: Received push message: 
"Tue Sep 02 12:13:09 GMT+200 2014 com.vaadin.client.VConsole"
INFO: JSON parsing took 1ms app
"Tue Sep 02 12:13:09 GMT+200 2014 com.vaadin.client.VConsole"
INFO: Handling message from server"
```

This log is produced by Vaadin console by accessing it from remote computer (over the network)

```
Tue Sep 02 12:11:00 GMT+200 2014 
com.vaadin.client.VConsole INFO: Making UIDL Request with params: 
Tue Sep 02 12:11:00 GMT+200 2014 
com.vaadin.client.VConsole INFO: Sending push message: 
[one minute passes ... UI unresponsive now]
Tue Sep 02 12:12:20 GMT+200 2014 
com.vaadin.client.VConsole INFO: Sending heartbeat request... 
Tue Sep 02 12:12:20 GMT+200 2014 
com.vaadin.client.VConsole INFO: Received push message:
Tue Sep 02 12:12:20 GMT+200 2014 
com.vaadin.client.VConsole INFO: JSON parsing took 1ms
Tue Sep 02 12:12:20 GMT+200 2014 
com.vaadin.client.VConsole INFO: Handling message from server 
[UI back to normal]
```

If you compare these two logs you will see the diffrence what causes "Received push messages" to be called. On localhost its normal: server receives push message after push message was sended. In remote access, server receives it only after client (browser) sends occasionally "heartbeat request".

Do you have any hints for me, where the problem may lie? FYI the rest of application (that doesn't contains complex tables) works just fine (same as on localhost). This happens on every major browser (FF, IE, Chrome)

Comment: Does the UI freeze on real network in both cases: few rows, 1000 thousand rows?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by disabling push mode in Vaadin.